# What liqueurs can be paired with a particular movie?

Tags: recommendations, pairing, liqueur

I enjoy watching movies with friends as a group and was hoping that some of you could possibly come up with a recommendation and pairing of a liqueur or two with a particular movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Hollywood blockbusters are well paired with beer. For example boxing scenes from **Rocky** fit *Budweiser*.
Hollywood classic may differ. In my opinion, **Gone With The Wind** requires *Bourbon*, and **My Fair Lady** is all about *Campaign*. **Forrest Gump** should fit *Dr. Pepper* but you can improve the drink with *Bourbon* or *Whiskey*. And of course **Zorro** must go with *Tequila*. **Jesus Christ Superstar** best fit to *red wine* and *dry bread* as a snack ("*This is my blood and this is my body. Remember this every time you eat and drink.*")
Some movies do not match a single drink. For example, **National Lampoon European Vacation** require *Scotch* for British episode, *cheap red wine* for French, *Bavarian beer* for German, and *Cinzano* for Italian.
And never forget **pickle juice** for the next morning. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make the following recommendation for the "Harry Potter" series.

[Mandrágora Liqueur](https://www.absinthes.com/en/liqueur-mandragora-liqueur-100-cl-p2029) from the Basque region of Spain.

> This liqueur from Navarra (in Spain) contains mandrake extract – a plant whose medicinal properties are the subject of many myths and legends.  Alkaloid, an active component contained in the plant, can supposedly initiate hallucinatory experiences.
>
> The legend goes that a mandrake elixir was consumed by witches who were learning how to fly.  Mandrake is also a key ingredient in many of the magical elixirs present in the famous “Harry Potter” series.
>
> In Harry Potter, as well as in other more traditional myths, mandrake root is portrayed with human characteristics since the root itself is said to resemble a human body.

[image: Liquor Mandrake "Mandrágora"]

[Liquor Mandrake "Mandrágora](http://www.alandia.de/liquor-mandrake-mandragora.html)"